# does postgresql log statement duration includes CLIENT time?

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple question about the duration of statements, which appear in the logs when using :

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

or

```
log_duration = on
```

Does this include client-time ? (i.e the time spent to send the data to the client). Or is it server-side only ?

According to different tests I made, it seems not to be, but I'd like to have your confirmation.

Note : I run pg 12

Thanks !

Comment: They do not include client time (i.e., the time spent to send the data to the client). These settings only measure and log the duration of query execution on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

It is the time until the server finished processing, which includes sending the data. But it won't include any processing time on the client — the client need not even have received all the data yet.